# How to calculate this exponential integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am trying to calculate

$\int_0^{+\infty}\log_2(1+ax)\frac{1}{a}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx$

by using the integration by parts method like:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty}\log_2(1+ax)\frac{1}{a}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx &= -\int_0^{+\infty}\log_2(1+ax)(e^{-\frac{x}{a}})'dx\\
&=\log_2(1+ax)e^{-\frac{x}{a}}|_0^{+\infty} + \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{a}{\ln2(1+ax)}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{a}{\ln2(1+ax)}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx = \frac{a}{\ln2}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+ax)}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx\\
&= \frac{a}{\ln2}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{a^2}}{-\frac{1}{a^2}(1 + ax)}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx = \frac{-\frac{1}{a}}{\ln2}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{x}{a}}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}dx\\
&= \frac{-\frac{1}{a}}{\ln2}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}e^{-\frac{1}{a^2}}}{(-\frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{x}{a})e^{-\frac{1}{a^2}}}dx \\
&= \frac{-\frac{1}{a}e^{\frac{1}{a^2}}}{\ln2}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}-\frac{1}{a^2}}}{(-\frac{x}{a}-\frac{1}{a^2})}dx\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

How can I further integrate the $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}-\frac{1}{a^2}}}{(-\frac{x}{a}-\frac{1}{a^2})}dx$ in order to get a closed form expression?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The exponential dosent depend on x...it should be outside the integral...and what is the derivative of the exponential ?

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply, Isham.
I am sorry I didn't get your point...

Comment: $\frac 1 a e^{-\frac 1 a}$ dosent depend on the variable x...so your integral is just $ \int \log(u) du$

Comment: Oops, it is a typo. What about now? Thank you so much!

Comment: Lol it looks better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Continuing from where you left: $$I =\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x/a-1/a^2}}{-x/a-1/a^2}\, dx$$ Substituting $u = \frac{x} {a} + \frac1{a^2} \implies du = \frac1{a} \, dx$ gives us: $$I = a \int_{\frac1{a^2}}^{\infty} - \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \, du$$ which is the exponential integral $E_1(u)$.

Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Don't you need to change the bounds of integration? As written, the integral diverges.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help!
However, I don't know how to get a closed-form expression for this $E_i(u)$.
I am truly sorry I know less about the exponential integration like $E_i(u)$.
Would you please suggest me some method in order to get the closed-form expression of $E_i(u)$?

Comment: @zhd The closed form expression is $E_1(u)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply, Kajeld.
I can calculate this with matlab or mathemaica now?
Let me try.

Comment: You're welcome, though if i'm not mistaken the integral still diverges. It should be: $$I=-a\int_{1/a^2}^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{u}du=a\ \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$